# Raspberry Pi shutdown destroys file system

Tags: crash, filesystems, shutdown, raspberry-pi

I trying to write a small c program witch reads out an GPIO pin to shutdown the pi externally. The triggering of the signal is working well. The program is started by LXDE as autostart application. If the program detects the shutdown signal it's performing:

```
sync();
system("halt");
```

Why does this program damage my ext4 file system after a couple of reboots. There is no fixed number of reboots necessary to damage the system. I don't see any difference by writing halt to command line. I'm using the newest version of the firmware(last update today) and also the kernel is up to date(last update today).

Does anybody have an good idea about it?

Comment: By now I'm performing some long time tests with my new program that is running without the sync() command before halt. By now this is still working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This app is a good idea, i wonder nothing like this is already existing...

I think the problem is the "halt" command.
You shuold use the explicit command "shutdown -h now" instead.

[For further reading see Anthony Lawrence](http://aplawrence.com/Linux/halt_shutdown_reboot.html)